# Watson disambiguation

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-assistant-solutions

I am trying to create a disambiguate node between the top two intents in a generic fashion. So during run time watson will not know which would be the intents that would cause disambiguation so I cannot hard code the value for the options I want to show the user.

For. e.g if someone asks what is slots?

and if the top two intents was intents[0].intent is "Watson-assistant" and " and intents[1].intent is "Music"

I want to ask the user, are you asking for Slots with respect to

1) Option Label 1:
2) Option Label 2: <

What is the value that I can pass dynamically so the same input is rerouted to that intent. I tried sending the intent as the same value but that did not work

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can actually send in the intents object directly. instead of passing in input.text you can just send in the intents object and then Watson will not try to classify the text. So Id recommend passing both the input text and the intent object so Watson has no chance of missing it in case there are also entities.

This is currently a premium only feature built in to the service as well, and we're evaluating the best ways to roll it out.